# gvisGeoChart with shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis, shinydashboard, gvisgeomap

Unable to get output for givsGeoChart in my shiny Dashboard.

Below is the code for the same.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googleVis)

ui <- dashboardPage(
       dashboardHeader(),
       dashboardSidebar(),
       dashboardBody(
          htmlOutput("Accidents")
                    )
                   )

server <- function(input, output) {

      output$Accidents <- renderGvis({
            gvisGeoChart(Dum, "States","Road_Accident",
            options=list(region="IN",displayMode="regions",resolution="provinces",width="100%"))
            })
          }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above code doesn't work.

```
GeoStates_IN <- gvisGeoChart(Dum, "States","Road_Accident",options=list(region="IN",displayMode="regions",resolution="provinces",width="100%"))
plot(GeoStates_IN)
```

whereas this code works.Unable to figure out what is missing in above code.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem has something to do with your `options()` or data. Is your variable dum cotaining columns "States" and "Road_Accident". Have you included the data in `server.R`?

This works:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googleVis)

ui <- dashboardPage(
       dashboardHeader(),
       dashboardSidebar(),
       dashboardBody(
          htmlOutput("Accidents")
                    )
                   )

server <- function(input, output) {

      output$Accidents <- renderGvis({
            data(Exports)
            #map<-gvisGeoChart(Exports, "States","Road_Accident",
            #options=list(region="IN",displayMode="regions",resolution="provinces",width="100%"))
            map<-gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar='Country', colorvar='Profit',
                   options=list(projection="kavrayskiy-vii"))
            return(map)
            })
          }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```